# Keeping hexadecimal numbers, and text that only has A-F separate

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

Among other more specific and non-problematic ones, I have the following lexer rules:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+ {
    yylval.string = strdup(yytext);
    return FILENAME;
}

 /* 32-bit numbers */
[a-fA-F0-9]{1,8} {
    std::stringstream ssh;
    ssh << std::hex << yytext;
    ssh >> yylval.u32.hex;
    std::stringstream ssd;
    ssd << std::dec << yytext;
    ssd >> yylval.u32.dec;
    return NUMBER;
}
```

The "NUMBER" rule is already a kludge because I can't distinguish HEX from DEC base numbers in the grammar I'm implementing.  Hex numbers have no prefix, it's all context-based.  So in the parser rules I just pick the number from the struct that I know I need.

It seems like I need to extend this even further.  I have a "filename" type, which is just any alphanumeric string that at the least begins with an alpha character, followed by any alphanumeric (as defined above).  Problem is, a filename like `fffff` is causing incorrect parsing.  It feels like the only way I can take care of this is to combine the NUMBER and FILENAME into something like `ALPHANUMERIC`, where I would do something like:

```
 /* 32-bit numbers, strings, sigh... */
[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,8} {
    std::stringstream ssh;
    ssh << std::hex << yytext;
    ssh >> yylval.alphanumeric.hex;
    std::stringstream ssd;
    ssd << std::dec << yytext;
    ssd >> yylval.alphanumeric.dec;
    yylval.alphanumeric.string = strdup(yytext);
    return ALPHANUMERIC;
}
```

Then I would have a be a bit smarter in the parser and check for an initial alpha, and use the right struct field.

Is this a common compromise?  It feels wrong, and the more liberal the lexing, I'm sure I'm going to create holes I haven't tested where it will either fail or capture too much.  I'll end up converting lots of strings like "hello" to `hex` and `dec` values needlessly.

Comment: If the hexadecimal number `face` is ambiguous in some context, that will not only be confusing for your lexer. It will also confuse your users. (Also, it seems illiberal to restrict filenames to letter-initial alphanumerics, but I suppose you have some other syntax in mind for other filenames.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is to use different flex rules for the different classes of tokens that can occur, with A_OR_B tokens for things that might be two different things:

```
[0-9]+ {
    yylval.u32 = strtol(yytext, 0, 10);
    return NUMBER; }
[a-fA-F][a-fA-F0-9]* {
    yylval.string = strdup(yytext);
    return NUMBER_OR_NAME; }
[a-fA-F0-9]+ {
    yylval.u32 = strtol(yytext, 0, 16);
    return NUMBER; }
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* {
    yylval.string = strdup(yytext);
    return NAME; }
```

Flex will always try to match the longest match, but when multiple patterns match the same length, it will match the first one.

In your parser, you use rules like:

```
name: NAME | NUMBER_OR_NAME ;

number: NUMBER | NUMBER_OR_NAME { $$ = strtol($1, 0, 16); free($1); } ;
```

Comment: Thanks, that would clean things up.  I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a differentiation of dec and hex like hexnumber and decnumber, but being purely context-based you would have to define some constraints like a filename would have to use at least 9 characters since this wouldn't be a valid 32 bits hex.

Comment: If I were defining the grammar, I'd require strings to be quoted, hex numbers to be prefixed with 0x, etc...  But unfortunately it's not my grammar to define. :)